# Keyof that is also of type T

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to restrict `keyof T` so that it only accepts keys that are of a certain type? Suppose the following:

```
interface Something {
    id: number;  
    name: string;  
    value1: FancyType;  
    value2: FancyType;  
    value3: FancyType;
}

function someFunction(key: keyof Something) {
   // do something to a FancyType
}
```

`someFunction` would accept `id | name | value1 | value2 | value3`, is there a way to restrict it to keys of type `FancyType`, ie `value1 | value2 | value3`?

Comment: Do you have any control over the definition of `FancyType`?  There is a pre-2.8 way of doing this, but it involves augmenting `FancyType` with a brand property.

Comment: @jclaz possibly, please post an answer if you know it :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since TypeScript 2.8 this is possible with [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) ([Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20FancyType%20%3D%20%22fancy%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Something%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value1%3A%20FancyType%3B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value2%3A%20FancyType%3B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value3%3A%20FancyType%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FancyProperties%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20FancyType%20%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20someFunction(key%3A%20keyof%20FancyProperties%3CSomething%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20something%20to%20a%20FancyType%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AsomeFunction(%22id%22)%3B%0D%0AsomeFunction(%22value2%22)%3B)).

```
type FancyProperties<T> = Pick<T, { 
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends FancyType ? K : never 
}[keyof T]>;


function someFunction(key: keyof FancyProperties<Something>) {
   // do something to a FancyType
}

someFunction("id"); // Error
someFunction("value2"); // OK
```

Comment: +1, thanks! I'm going to hold off with accepting a little bit in the _faint hope_ that somebody comes up with something for 2.6.2 ;-)

Comment: Good luck @Robus 

Comment: In this case you could also use `type KeyOfFancyProperties<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends FancyType ? K : never }[keyof T];` without Pick, right?

Comment: @Nixie, I don't follow, the code in your comment doesn't compile, do you want to link to the full implementation you had in mind?

Comment: @Motti, I did a few edits, most recent one should compile. I am just using X from your Pick<T, X> type, that should serve the original TC need to have 'keyof' type, as I guess.

Comment: Although this is an excellent answer, the following will still not compile, why?:

`function someFunction<T extends Something>(x: T, key: keyof FancyProperties<T>): FancyType {
    return x[key]
}`

Comment: @JørgenTvedt, if you just say `x: Something` instead of being generic on `x` the function works. `function someFunction1(x: Something, key: keyof FancyProperties<Something>): FancyType { 
    return x[key];
}`.
 I guess having the generic complicates the logic a bit too much for the compiler.

Comment: @Motti - I see.  I can't easily convert my function to using a single type like that, but it works on the input validation - so I guess I just have to use a cast.

Comment: I am new to typescript and reading about conditional types. I don't understand how `[keyof T]` works after defining a type like `{ 
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends FancyType ? K : never 
}[keyof T]` . I didn't see this syntax while reading about type. Can someone please explain what it does?

Comment: @aditya81070 when I wrote it I sort of understood it, now your guess is as good as mine....

Comment: @Motti I played a little bit with syntax and find out that it is kind of defining an index signature where keys can be `keyof T`. I am not 100% sure but it is kind of accessing an object(here type) properties.

Comment: @aditya81070 that much I remember.  It basically defines an object who's keys are based on `T`'s keys in cases where the value is of specific type. The `[keyof T]` at the end maps properties out of the object defined.  So `{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}['a'|'c']` maps to `{ a:1, c: 3 }`

Answer (score 9):

A better implementation of @Motti's answer is this:

```
type FilteredKeyOf<T, TK> = keyof Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TK ? K : never }[keyof T]>;
```

It uses the same principle of using conditional types and `never`, but parameterizes the the type your properties should extend in `TK`.

You can use it with more flexibility:

```
function someFunction(key: FilteredKeyOf<Something, FancyType>) {
  // do something to a FancyType
}
someFunction("id"); // error
someFunction("value2"); // okay
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I don't have a TS 2.6.2 compiler in front of me, so I can't double check if this works.  And as it involves augmentation to an existing type, it's not my favorite solution either (the 2.8 solution with conditional types suggested by @Motti is definitely the way to go).

That said, here's one way to try it.  I'm going to assume that `FancyType` is an interface somewhere and that you can [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) a property into it.  Here it is:

```
interface FancyType {
  '**fancyBrand**'?: never
}
```

So a value of type `FancyType` now is said to have an *optional* property whose key name is `**fancyBrand**` and whose value is of the impossible `never` type.  In practice that means that you don't need to create such a property, and existing values of type `FancyType` will not cause you any type errors.

Now for some helper type functions. `ValueOf<T>` just produces the union of property types of an object:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

So `ValueOf<{a: string, b: number}>` would be `string | number`.  And `Diff` takes two unions of string literals and removes those in the second one from the first one:

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = 
  ({ [K in T]: K } & { [K in U]: never } & { [k: string]: never })[T];
```

So `Diff<'a'|'b'|'c', 'a'>` would be `'b'|'c'`.

Finally we're ready to define `FancyKeys<T>`, the type function that returns the keys of `T` whose property values are `FancyType`:

```
type FancyKeys<T> = Diff<keyof T, ValueOf<
  { [K in keyof T]: (T[K] & { '**fancyBrand**': K })['**fancyBrand**'] }>>
```

And therefore `FancyKeys<Something>` would be `'value1'|'value2'|'value3'`:

```
function someFunction(key: FancyKeys<Something>) {
  // do something to a FancyType
}
someFunction("id"); // error
someFunction("value2"); // okay
```

`FancyKeys<T>` works by essentially intersecting `T` with a type whose keys are the same as `T`, and whose values each has a `'**fancyBrand**'` property equal to the key.  For properties of `FancyType` type, the resulting `'**fancyBrand**'` property will still be `never` or `undefined`.  But for those of any other type (which lacks a `'**fancyBrand**'` key), the resulting property will be the key.

This turns `Something` into `{id: 'id', name: 'name', value1: undefined, value2: undefined, value3: undefined}`.  When you take `ValueOf<T>` for that, it becomes `'id'|'name'|undefined`.  And for some reason I can't quite fathom, it lets you take the `Diff<keyof Something, U>` to produce just `'value1'|'value2'|'value2'`... not sure why it allows `undefined` in `Diff<>`, but I'm not complaining.  If it hadn't let us do that, the only viable alternative would be to make the `**fancyBrand**` property *required* in `FancyType`, which would make your life more trouble than you want when you try to instantiate it (unless it's a class, in which case it's not a huge deal).

So this works, but feels yucky to me, and I've more or less given up this kind of hacky craziness to use conditional types instead.  Still, hope it helps to know about it.  Good luck!