# TypeScript index types, how to add constraint on T[K]

Tags: typescript

In typescript, we can use index types like this  :

```
interface Dummy {
    name: string;
    birth: Date;
}

function doSomethingOnProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, name: K): void {
    o[name]; // do something, o[name] is of type T[K]
}

var dummy = { name: "d", birth: new Date() };

doSomethingOnProperty(dummy, "name");
```

**Question** :

How to add a generic constraint to only accept name of property of certain type (is it possible ?) :

```
// Generic constraint on T[K] ? T[K] must be of type Date
function doSomethingOnDATEProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, name: K): void {
    o[name];
}

// should not compile,
// should accept only the name of propery "birth" which is of type date
doSomethingOnDATEProperty(dummy, "name");
```

Comment: I answered a very similar question today https://stackoverflow.com/a/49797062/3848

Comment: @Motti while similar  your solution from that question has a problem `o[name]` will not be typed as `FancyType` that was not an issue there as it was not required, here the requirement is that you can access the field of the object in a typed way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
function doSomethingOnDATEProperty<T extends { [P in K]: Date }, K extends keyof T>(o: T, name: K): void {
    let d = o[name]; // do something, o[name] is of type T[K] but also Date
    d.getFullYear(); // Valid
}

var dummy = { name: "d", birth: new Date() };

doSomethingOnDATEProperty(dummy, "birth");
```