# stating that a property is not only "keyof" of a type but also an array of something

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
export function listMutations<S, M extends Model>(postfix: keyof S): MutationTree<S> {
  return {
    ADD(state, payload) {
      state[postfix].push(payload.value)
    },
    CHANGED(state, payload) {},
    REMOVED(state, payload) {},
    RELATIONSHIP_ADDED(state, payload) {},
    RELATIONSHIP_REMOVED(state, payload) {},
  }
}
```

Where `S` represents a particular "state tree" and `M` is a given data model. The "model" is meant to fit into the state tree. For example, imagine that the state tree looked like this:

```
export interface StateTree<M> {
  all: M[],
  byId: ...
}
```

the `postfix` value passed into the function determines whether the property is "all" or something else but it is assumed that -- given the `postfix` property -- that:

1. `postfix` is a *keyof* of the state tree
2. and the value of the `postfix` property is an array of `M`

I have typed for the first condition but because this typing doesn't tell the type system that the value is always an array I get a type error on the `.push()` call.

I then looked at this question for reference: [keyof-that-is-also-of-type-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796842/keyof-that-is-also-of-type-t). This helped somewhat and led to this attempt:

```
export type ListPropertyCandidates<T> = Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Model[] ? K : never }[keyof T]>

export function listMutations<T>(postfix: keyof ListPropertyCandidates<T>): MutationTree<T> {
  return {
    ADD(state, payload) {
      state[postfix].push(payload.value)
    },
    CHANGED(state, payload) {},
    REMOVED(state, payload) {},
    RELATIONSHIP_ADDED(state, payload) {},
    RELATIONSHIP_REMOVED(state, payload) {},
  }
}
```

I'd thought that inclusion of `T[K] extends Model[]` in the **ListPropertyCandidates** might get me there but the typing error persists in that it doesn't recognize the `state[postfix]` as always being an array.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You refer it as `prefix` outside the code, but name it `postfix` inside the code, are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could define the type of `state` like so 
`ADD<V>(state: {postfix: V[]}, payload: {value: V}) { state.postfix.push(payload.value);}`

Comment: Sorry it should say `postfix` everywhere; will update

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without defining the type of `state` itself

```
function listMutations<S, M extends Model>(postfix: keyof S): MutationTree<S> {
  return {
    ADD(state: Record<keyof S, M[]>, payload: {value: M}) {
      state[postfix].push(payload.value);
    },
    ...
  }
}
```